# Match the content of double square brackets

Tags: regex, square-bracket

I have a string and I want to match the content of double square brackets:
Example:

```
<p><span>"Sed ut perspiciatis vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</span></p><p><span>[[image file="2013-12/5s_1.jpg" alt="IPhone 5s" title="IPhone 5s" ]]</span></p><p><span>[[download file="2013-12/modulo-per-restituzione-prodotti-.pdf" icon="icon" text="" title="Download" ]]</span></p>
```

Results:

```
download file="2013-12/module-res.pdf" icon="icon" text="" title="Download" 

image file="2013-12/5s_1.jpg" alt="IPhone 5s" title="IPhone 5s"
```

Consider that these 2 strings can contain any type of characters, I tried this solution but I have problems with other characters:

```
\[\[[\w+\s*="-\/]*\]\]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

```
\[\[[^\]]*\]\]
```

This class would match anything but "]"

See it here on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?37lls)

To avoid the square brackets beeing part of the result, you can either use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

```
\[\[([^\]]*)\]\]
```

and get the result from group 1

or use [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (if it is supported by your regex engine)

```
(?<=\[\[)[^\]]*(?=\]\])
```

See it on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?37llv)

Comment: Ok, this is perfect for my scope. Thank you @stema your solution without the brackets is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use lookaheads:

```
\[\[(([^]]|[]](?!\]))*)\]\]
```

meaning:

```
\[\[    # match 2 literal square brackets
 (      # match
    [^]]         # a non-square bracket
    |            # or
    []](?!\])    # a square bracket not followed by a square bracket
 )*     # any number of times
\]\]    # match 2 literal right square brackets
```

Or you can use lazy quantifiers:

```
\[\[(.*?)\]\]
```

Comment: Thank you, this also can be my solution, well explained @perreal.

Answer (score 0):

This regexp will select the square brackets but by using **group(1)** you will be able to get only the content:

```
"\\[\\[\\(.*\\)\\]\\]"
```